# How to smudge a pixelized or jagged image to a painterly effect?

Tags: krita

I'm exporting a base model from zbrush to use as a base from a painting. I don't wish to work in high topology, so exported models show thousands of small polygons.

What is the best way to smudge these so that I can gradually work up the model to appear as painted strokes instead?

Edit: Here is an example...
[image]

Whether the polygons be pronounced, or subtle (or maybe even appearing as rough or pixelated) I am simply looking for a way to smudge them into strokes. I just need a general way...the details ...case by case, I can solve.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Any chance you could share the image?  It's really difficult to tell you anything specific without seeing what you have to begin with. Questions with insufficient detail inevitably get put on hold for being too broad. Thanks.

Comment: Have you a 3D model or a flat 2D scene image? Can you get it as 3D?